# Why MediatorLiveData does not observe two different sources?

Tags: android, kotlin, repository-pattern, android-livedata

I have two Room queries.

```
@Query("Select * from accountGroup")
fun getAll(): LiveData<List<AccountGroupDto>>


@Query("Select * from accounts")
fun getAll(): LiveData<List<AccountDto>>
```

With those 2 result lists i want to create a new list of ShareItem

```
data class ShareItem
(val accountId: Int, val accountGroupId: Int, val isGroup: Boolean)
```

The combined list i want to observe it in my activity.
So i have the repository which implementsa MediatorLiveData that adds two sources and i want for each item to transform (creating a ShareItem) and add it to a mutableLiveData andgive it to viewModel.

```
override fun getShareItems(): LiveData<List<Int>> {
        val shareItems = MutableLiveData<List<ShareItem>>()
        val liveDataMerger = MediatorLiveData<List<Int>>()
                
        liveDataMerger.addSource(accountGroupsDao.getAll()) {  groups ->
            // Transform each element in ShareItem ??
            println("Group log")
        }
        liveDataMerger.addSource(accountsDao.getAll()) { accounts ->
            // Transform each element in ShareItem ??
            println("Account log")
        }
        
        return shareItems
    }
```

However i never see the System.out in the console. What am i missing since the database clearly is full of data?

Comment: you add sources to `liveDataMerger` but return `shareItems`

Comment: The point is that i dont see and System.out in the Logcat. Its like nothing is called

Comment: bc you don't observe `liveDataMerger` LiveData. "onChanged callback (lambda) will be called only when this MediatorLiveData is active".

Comment: IR42 is right. I have to add groups / accounts inside liveDateMerger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However i never see the System.out in the console. What am i missing
> since the database clearly is full of data?

Is there an `Observer`? `LiveData` only starts working once there is at least one `Observer`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I was never registered an Observer to the Livedata.